# Why session bean method throw EjbTransactionRolledbackException when RuntimeException was thrown

Tags: java, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1, bean-validation

I am trying to persist the entity with constraint validation,
when invoke persist - there is constraint that thrown and the caller get `EjbTransactionRolledbackException`...
so I try to call the validation explicit and throw `ConstraintViolationException`/`RuntimeException` and still the caller get `EjbTransactionRolledbackException`...
when I throw `MyException` extends `Exception` - the caller get `MyException`

Even when I call explicit `sc.setRollBackOnly` it's still happened :(

This shouldn't be the behavior.

what's going on?

Configuration:

Netbeans 6.9.1
Glassfish 3.0.1
JPA 2.0 (EclipseLink)
EJB 3.1

Thanks!!!

```
@Stateless
public class My {

@PersistenceContext
EntityManager em;

@Resource
Validator  validator;

public Order checkout(Order order) {
    Set<ConstraintViolation<Order>> set = validator.validate(order, Default.class);

    if (!set.isEmpty()) {
        sc.setRollbackOnly();
        //throw new ConstraintViolationException(new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>(set));
        throw new RuntimeException();
    }

    this.em.persist(order);
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> so I try to call the validation explicit and throw ConstraintViolationException/RuntimeException and still the caller get EjbTransactionRolledbackException...

Providing the full stacktrace might help. Anyway, I wonder how you are calling your EJB and if you're propagating a transaction, in which case throwing a EJBTransactionRolledbackException is the right behavior in case of a system exception. But the following blog post might help:

> #### [Constraint violated, transaction rolled back](http://wolf-71.blogspot.com/2009/10/constraint-violated-transaction-rolled.html)
>
> When using bean validation on JPA
>   entities within an EJB 3 bean you
>   would actually get an
>   EJBTransactionRolledbackException if
>   there is a constraint violation.
>
> ```
> javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: Invalid object at persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
> Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Invalid object at persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
> ```
>
> This is all nicely according to
>   specification, but not really
>   interesting information. You don't
>   really want to know what happened, you
>   want to know what went wrong.
>
> So I recommend adding the following to
>   your ejb-jar.xml:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <ejb-jar
>         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
>         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
>                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
>         version="3.0">
>    <assembly-descriptor>
>       <application-exception>
>          <exception-class>javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException</exception-class>
>          <rollback>true</rollback>
>       </application-exception>
>    </assembly-descriptor>
> </ejb-jar>
> ```
>
> That way you can directly access your
>   violations.

#### Resources

- On EJB and application vs system exception:

  - [Best practices in EJB exception handling](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-ejbexcept/index.html)
  - [16.6. Exceptions and Transactions](http://codeidol.com/java/netbeans/Transactions/Exceptions-and-Transactions/)
- On Bean Validation

  - [Constraint violated, transaction rolled back](http://wolf-71.blogspot.com/2009/10/constraint-violated-transaction-rolled.html)

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ejb-jar
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
                            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd"
        version="3.0">
   <assembly-descriptor>
      <application-exception>
         <exception-class>javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException</exception-class>
         <rollback>true</rollback>
      </application-exception>
   </assembly-descriptor>
</ejb-jar>

Comment: Great answer! if I put the above XML in the ejb-jar.xml, I tell to the EJB context that if javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException was thrown, the caller will get application exception (without destroying the session bean) and not a system exception

Answer (score 0):

Just to integrate @Pascal's answer, it is also possible to mark Exception (if it's on your own) with

```
 @javax.ejb.ApplicationException(rollback = true)
 public class UncheckedException extends RuntimeException {...}
```